# Incoherent Range into Recordset

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I got a problem with the Recordset I'm using in my Excel VBA Project. I'm trying to read a certain range into the Recordset and til now it always worked. But this time around I want to get a incoherent range, which in my case consists of columns of a table, and give this range to the recordset through the following function (got it from @Martin Dreher)

```
'this is how I set the range
Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("Tablename[[field1]:[field2]], " & _
    "Tablename[[field3]:[field4]], Tablename[[field5]:[field6]]")

'this is the function I set my recordset with
Function GetRecordset(rng As Range)

    Dim xlXML       As Object
    Dim rst         As Object

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML Replace(rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML), "rs:name="" ", "rs:name=""")
    rst.Open xlXML

    Set GetRecordset = rst

End Function
```

When I select the range via VBA and it is the one I want but when calling getRecordset and afterwords copy the data out of the recordset all I get is the data of the first range.

I edited the names of the variables since there is some internal data involved.

Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you found it useful. Please make sure to mark helpful answers and close open threads, if you consider the problem solved.

On topic:

Add `Debug.Print rng.value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)` inside your function for debugging. You'll see that the XML only contains your first range, even if you union your ranges with, well, `Union` first.

Afaik there's no fix for this. Try to fix with continuous ranges.

However, if you absolutely need two ranges in one recordset, and you can guarantee they have both the same number of rows and that each `Row(i)` in `A` belongs to `Row(i)` in `B`, then a workaround would be to

- create a new sheet on the fly with `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add`
- output your `Union`-range-values to that sheet in a continuous range starting at `.Cells(1,1)`
- retrieve the XML from pass `.UsedRange`
- read the XML into your recordset
- `.Delete` the worksheet with no prompts
- End with `End with`

Put this into your `GetRecordset`-Function, since, at the same time, it solves the problem you had with two header rows. If performance is an issue, consider passing an additional `Boolean` to your function to determine if your function uses the workaround or not.

Hope that helps.

**Edit:** We cannot just delete an unused`Field` from an open recordset. As you might expect, every workaround is a bit dirty.

Since I would have to test performance, I can only give you some ideas for testing.

1. with the use of `Worksheets.Add` mentioned above, a slower performance is to be expected if you do it repeatedly.

   However, instead of creating a `Worksheet` in each loop, you could

   - create a new 
     `Worksheet` once,
   - `.UsedRange.Cells.Clear` after each iteration
   - `.Delete` once at the end.
2. if you use `.CopyFromRecordset`, and start with blank output-sheets, it's likely faster to just

   - loop `Cells` in `Rows(1)` of your Ouput
   - if the header is in your "unwanted"-list then `.EntireColumn.Delete`

I would give 1. a try.

Comment: Hey, First of all how can I mark your answer as helpful? I tried to press the "upvote" button but I got a message that since I have less than 15 reputation the feedback will be counted but not shown in public. Secondly how can I close a thread? I wasn't able to find anything about that or do I just have to write a answer with -closed- or something like that?

To get back to topic...
The workaround would certainly work for my case but as you stated in your last sentence, the performance would propable suffer from it. I will try it out and get back to you as soon as I'm finished. Thank you!

Comment: I did write workaround and the performance certainly suffers severly. Maybe if I described the problem a little bit clearer or differently you could show me another way to go. The basic table has like 25 columns (not sure) and in this case I either want only 20 columns to be read into the recordset or only 20 columns copied out of it. I hope you get a better understanding by that and may help me out a bit.

Comment: see **Edit** for a thought on how to speed things up. not sure there is a nice way of doing this.
For marking answered questions, you should be able to check the grey checkmark under the up/downvote button.

Comment: Going to test that aswell. Completly off topic, could you explain me wildcards regarding filtering. I'm trying to filter all data of one year by using `rst.Filter = "Start = '*2016*'"` but it doesn't work. Any ideas? I researched a bit but it seems that it isnt quite the usual way to use recordsets in excel

Comment: i obviously meant `rst.Filter = "Start LIKE '*2016*'"`

Comment: Whats really weird is that I can use `rst.Filter = "Anlass LIKE '*A*'"`but not the one above. I thought that all fields have the same type? aren't they all seen as strings?

Comment: No. Each `Field` has a `Type` property, which is set after the data is read. There can be some difficulties if you got mixed data in a column. However, normal strings, booleans, dates and integers are pretty stable. 
Inspect your `rst`-object variable after it is set, if you got any doubts that excel set the correct field type. Ask Dr. Google on how to date-filter syntax https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/filtering-a-record-set-based-on-a-date.2924019/

Comment: okay so I found out that it's 135 which seems to be a date which is correct. does this mean that I will have to change the filter considering it isn't a text?

Comment: I'm not able to make it... I've read pretty much every thread that exists about this topic -.- I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: there are so many people using the same syntax as i am using now but it seems that i just cant find the right format of the date...
`rst.Filter = "Beginn >= #" & Format(anfang, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# AND <=#" & _
        Format(ende, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"`